# Change of basis linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S : M_{2,2} → M_{2,2}$ be the linear transformation defined by $S(A) = A + A^T$
.
Consider the bases for $M_{2,2}$ given by:

$$B = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

and

$$c = \left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -3&0\\0&2 \end{bmatrix} \right\}$$

(a) Determine the transition matrix $P_{B,C}$ from C to B.

(b) Determine the transition matrix $P_{C,B}$ from B to C.

This question is very different from the types I have encountered thus far so please help me solve it, I have been struggling for a few hours now.

Comment: This not so different from the usual posts on this topic, see [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/let-s-m2-2-m2-2-linear-transformation-defined-s--consider-bases-m2-2-given-determine-trans-q40886735) for exactly the same post.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that link's solution

Comment: Have a look at this site how to do such questions. Then you won't need any link's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that by matrix representation of the same vector $v$ with respect to the two basis

- $v=M_Bv_B$
- $v=M_Cv_C$

with

$$M_B=\left(\begin{array} &1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 &0 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1&0\\ 0 & 0 &0 & 1 \end{array} \right), \quad M_C=\left(\begin{array} &1 & 2 & 0 & -3 \\ 0 & -1 &0 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1&0\\ 0 & 0 &1 & 2 \end{array} \right)$$

therefore

$$M_Bv_B=M_Cv_C \implies v_B=M_B^{-1}M_Cv_C \quad \land \quad v_C=M_C^{-1}M_Bv_B$$

that is $P_{C,B}=M_C^{-1}M_B$ and $P_{B,C}=M_B^{-1}M_C$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: Hi i found another resource that suggests: $P_{C,B}=M_C^{-1}M_B$ and $P_{B,C}=M_B^{-1}M_C$

Comment: Can you please recheck the suggestion you gave, this topic is confusing me a lot and I am really grateful that you are taking out time to help me out

Comment: @JohnSmith Which step is not clear to you?

Comment: I stumbled across working from another source which concluded $P_{B,C} = M_{B}^{-1} M_{C}$ which is different from what you have concluded

Comment: @JohnSmith Ah ok that's only a matter of definition. I'm assumig $P_{B,C}$takes in a vector representation in basis C and returns the vector representation in basis B. If we choose a different definition we only need to exchange the matrices!

Comment: @JohnSmith I've edited according to your convention!

Comment: thank you so much. Sorry I am doing mathematics after a long time and often get super confused

Comment: @JohnSmith You are welcome! I had to be more precise with the notation I've assumed! Bye